# Segmentation by interaction in the campaign name marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

How do I create a segmentation in the marketing cloud of people who interacted with emails that contain specific names. For example, I sent campaigns with the name "events" and I want to filter all the people who clicked on the campaigns with those names!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine Click and Job data views, to find those who have clicked on links in your "events" campaign:

```
SELECT 
        _Click.SubscriberKey,
        _Click.EventDate AS ClickEventDate,
        _Click.URL,
        _Job.EmailName
FROM _Click
INNER JOIN _Job 
        ON _Click.JobID = _Job.JobID
WHERE
        _Job.EmailName = 'events'
```

https://dataviews.io/ can help you build this and similar queries